# First error: unexpected token: '('

Tags: apex, schedulebatch

i have First Error:

> Unexpected token: '(' in scheduled batch jobs

below is the code where the error referenced

```
global class batchCaseAttachmentDeletionClass implements Database.Batchable<SObject>  
{
    global String CaseQuery;
    global Date custom_closed_date;

    global batchCaseAttachmentDeletionClass()
     {
        CaseQuery = 'Select Id,custom_closed_date__c from Case where custom_closed_date__c=:Date.Today().AddDays(0)';
     }
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bcMain) {
  return Database.getQueryLocator(CaseQuery);
}

         global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bFinish)
{

}



// "Execute" is what is being run as a separate process per batch
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bcMain, List<SObject> lstBatchRecords) 
{
    Set<Id> caseId = new set<Id>();
    List<Case> cs_List = (List<Case>)lstBatchRecords;
    List<CaseComment> lst_CaseComment = new List<CaseComment>();

    for(Case cs : cs_List)
     {
        caseId.add(cs.id);
     }

  List<Attachment> listAttachment = new List<attachment>([Select Id,ParentId,Name,Body from Attachment where ParentId IN:
                                                          caseId]);


   for(Attachment attachmentRecd : listAttachment) 
    {
      CaseComment cseComment = new CaseComment();
      cseComment.ParentId = attachmentRecd.ParentId;
      cseComment.CommentBody = 'Attachment -'+ attachmentRecd.Name +  'have been deleted';
      lst_CaseComment.add(cseComment);
    }



    if(listAttachment!=null && listAttachment.size()>0)
     {
        try
         {
        delete listAttachment;
        insert lst_CaseComment;
         }catch(Exception e)
           {
             throw e;
           }
     }

     }

     }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is in following line which is a run time exception:

```
CaseQuery = 'Select Id,custom_closed_date__c from Case where ' +
    'custom_closed_date__c=:Date.Today().AddDays(0)';
```

Change it to following:

1. Easier: Its using `TODAY` [SOQL Date literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm)

   ```
   CaseQuery = 'Select Id,custom_closed_date__c from Case where ' +
       'custom_closed_date__c = TODAY';
   ```
2. Use appropriate Date or DateTime variable:

   ```
   Date dt = Date.Today().AddDays(0);
   CaseQuery = 'Select Id,custom_closed_date__c from Case where ' +
       'custom_closed_date__c =: dt';
   ```

Comment: [Relevant documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm).

Comment: @Rahul Sharma I am still getting below error

First error: line 1:90 no viable alternative at character '<EOF>'

Comment: you should not, can we see your code?

Answer (score -1):

Update the query string line, As it look for the value bind at the run time.

```
 CaseQuery = 'Select Id,custom_closed_date__c from Case where custom_closed_date__c= '+ Date.Today().AddDays(0);
```